# For any matrices $A$ and $B$ of the same size, show that $\mathrm{Im}(A ,B) = \mathrm{Im}(A) + \mathrm{Im}(B)$.

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, matrix-analysis

I just want to be more familiar with block matrices and while I am reading Fuhzen Zhang book, I found this problem

$\mathrm{Im}( A,B)$ means the range of the block matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} A & B\end{bmatrix}$$

i consider it as this

$$T=\begin{bmatrix} A & B\end{bmatrix}$$
$\mathrm{Im}(T)$={$\mathrm{Tx: x∈C^n}$}
$$Tx=\begin{bmatrix}A & B\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x1 &x2\end{bmatrix}^t$$$
$$Tx=Ax1 + Bx2$

so $\mathrm{Im}(T)$=$\mathrm{Im}(A)$+$\mathrm{Im}(B)$
is this true or i missed something
and sorry if i have a code mistakes i am just new in here

Comment: What does $\text{Im}(A,B)$? mean?

Comment: Your attempt is correct!

Answer (score 1):

$$T=\begin{bmatrix} A & B\end{bmatrix}$$
$\mathrm{Im}(T)$={$\mathrm{Tx: x∈C^n}$}
$$Tx=\begin{bmatrix}A & B\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x1 &x2\end{bmatrix}^t$$$
$$Tx=Ax1 + Bx2$

so $\mathrm{Im}(T)$=$\mathrm{Im}(A)$+$\mathrm{Im}(B)$